# According to the button 1 image is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function when the "user" click on the button shows an image, but each button shows a different image. So what I'm looking for is when the user clicks on another button the image of the previous one is hidden

And I also need some advice or a guide to do a doubleclick function, keep the id and it is shown in a text

I'm using javascript, but I also believe that there is a way using jquery

Sorry my English is not the best, although I think I understand.

```js
function showimage(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);

  if (element.classList) {
    element.classList.toggle(id);
  } else {
    var classes = element.className.split(" ");
    var i = classes.indexOf(id);

    if (i >= 0)
      classes.splice(i, 1);
    else
      classes.push(id);
    element.className = classes.join(" ");
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  overflow: ;
}

.background {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'avenir';
  src: url(../fonts/Avenir Next Heavy.otf)
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir Next LT Pro Heavy Condensed Italic';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(../fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-HeavyCnIt.woff) format('woff');
}

.general {
  background-image: url(../img/miSlJSc.png);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: -1%;
  width: 1584px;
  height: 900px;
}

.contain1 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 258px;
  width: 1048px;
  height: 254px
}

.contain2 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 526px;
  width: 1048px;
  height: 254px;
}

button {
  background: #005F38;
  background: rgba(0, 95, 56, 1);
  border-style: Solid;
  border-color: #112302;
  border-color: rgba(17, 35, 2, 1);
  border-width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 439px;
  top: 822px;
  width: 359px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px
}

#comprar {
  left: 1185px
}

.styletext {
  font-family: Avenir Next LT Pro Heavy Condensed Italic;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FCFCFC;
  color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
}

.boxsmall {
  background: #000000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  top: -14px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 117px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-width: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px
}

.boxbig {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  top: -5%;
  width: 249px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-width: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px
}

.boxsellect {
  background: #000000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  opacity: 0.65;
  position: absolute;
  left: 898px;
  top: 526px;
  width: 249px;
  height: 120px
}

.icon * {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 33px;
  transform: rotate(315deg)
}

#botella .icon * {
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px
}

#punoAmericano .icon * {
  width: 70px;
  height: 35px;
  left: 0px
}

.icon-p * {
  left: -10px;
  width: 92px;
  height: 72px;
}

#pistol_mk2 .icon-p {
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  left: -20px;
}

.statsPistol {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 70px 105px;
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/53/53524.svg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -270px;
  left: 1090px
}

.statsPistolmk2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 70px 105px;
  background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1034/1034131.svg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -270px;
  left: 1090px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    /*.general {display: none;}*/
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="full-screen">
    <div class="general">
                <div class="contain2">

        <button class="boxsmall" id="pistol" onclick="showimage('statsPistol')">
     <div class="icon-p">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/42/42829.svg">
     </div>
     <div id="statsPistol">
     </div>
    </button>

        <button class="boxsmall" id="pistol_mk2" onclick="showimage('statsPistolmk2')">
     <div class="icon-p">
      <img src="img/pistolas/Pistol-mk2-icon.png">
     </div>
     <div id="statsPistolmk2">
     </div>
    </button>


      </div>
      <button class="styletext" id="comprar">Comprar</button>
      <button class="styletext" id="salir">Salir</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. For a start, functions are not "clicked." You'll need to clarify what you mean by "I have a function that when clicked..."

Comment: Sorry my English is not the best, although I think I understand.

I have a function when the "user" click on the button shows an image, but each button shows a different image. So what I'm looking for is when the user clicks on another button the image of the previous one is hidden

Comment: Ok. So you want the click event handler to show the image on the button that has been clicked, and you want to hide all the other images. Right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all difficult to do using jQuery. Just hide all the images (including those that aren't showing), and show the one that has been clicked. You don't need to worry about hiding only the previous image, because you don't have enough buttons to improve perceived performance if you do.

The code works like this:

1. When you click on an element with the class `boxsmall`:
2. Hide all images that are inside any element with the class `boxsmall`.
3. Show the image that is inside the element that has been clicked.

A couple of other bits of advice:

1. Don't have any HTML elements with the same id. If you don't need an id, just leave it out.
2. Don't set duplicate CSS properties, as you have with some of your background and color properties. The lower of the two will override the upper one, so there's no point to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.boxsmall').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.boxsmall img').hide();
    $(this).find('img').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.boxsmall {
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="full-screen">
    <div class="general">
      <div class="contain1">

        <button class="boxsmall">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/42/42829.svg">
                </div>
            </button>
        <button class="boxsmall">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/42/42829.svg">
                </div>
            </button>
        <button class="boxsmall">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/42/42829.svg">
                </div>
            </button>
        <button class="boxsmall">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/42/42829.svg">
                </div>
            </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I think you explain me wrong and my mistake when putting the complete code .. The images of the buttons are always visible, but when pressing the bottles shows an image in another place not in the button

Edit the main post and I think it's clearer now

and thanks for helping me

Comment: @Rms I'm sorry, but this says something different from your post. Here you say the button images are always visible. In your post you say "when the user clicks on another button the image of the previous one is hidden." These two statements contradict each other.

Comment: As I said, I apologize if I explained wrong, and now edit the main thread, now I think it is better understood

Comment: @Rms The two statements still contradict each other.